# JBPM integration with web application organisation hierarchy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jbpm

I developed a spring and hibernate application that integrate with jbpm 6. I successfully started sample process designed in eclipse bpmn 2 plugin

I set actors id like below who are defined users in my web application.
I know there have to be a link between jbpm and my user table. But I couldn't find any explanation.

So my question is there a way to use my own predefined user-groups-positions etc. as activity responsible?

Sample Process
[image: Sample Process]

I tried to add some existing wep application user ids to actor list of User Task but this doesn't work of course

[image]

**Edit:** I'm working on jbpm-human-task-jpa source code to change organizational structure and I hope I will achive to accommodate the code with my own organization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to implement a custom [UserGroupCallback](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.2/javadocs/org/kie/api/task/UserGroupCallback.html). You will need to create a class that implements that interface and register it with the runtime. If you are using CDI, you can add the @ApplicationScoped annotation to the class and it should register. If are manually building the runtime you can register it like in the following code

```
RuntimeEnvironment environment = RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.Factory.get()
        .newDefaultBuilder()
        .entityManagerFactory(emf)
        .userGroupCallback(usergroupCallback)
```

Below is an example implementation of the getGroupsForUser method.

```
public List<String> getGroupsForUser(String userId, List<String> groupIds, List<String> allExistingGroupIds) {
    List<String> groups = new ArrayList<String>();
    if ("ismail".equals(userId)) {
        groups.add("admin");
        groups.add("project_manager");
    }
    return groups;
}
```

You can set a task assignment by Group by going in the User Task / Attributes / Group Id. You can use either admin or project_manager in that field. When you try to claim that task as the user ismail, it should be available. Instead of hard coding like it did, you can make a JDBC or JPA call to another database to perform the lookup.

Comment: I think this is not enough to force jbpm use my own user table to retrieve users. This interface allows me to change query strategy about whether user exists or not, isn't it?

Comment: The existsGroup and existsUser methods just check if the group or user exists. The getGroupsForUser is where you can specify which users belongs to which group. You will want to return a List of groups for the given userId parameter.

Comment: There is some namedqueries like find-possible-actors, in such queries OrganizationalEntity table (in which users and groups are stored) is used for both users and groups as a single table. I need to change this table in the queries. To be more clear, for users I need to use my own UserEntity table and Groups as GroupEntity table. This is what I need. Is that possible?

Comment: The getGroupsForUser method just needs to return a list of group ids that the specified user belongs to. Inside the method you could make a JDBC or JPA call into your own database to look up the group ids. For testing purposes, just hard code the assignments to get it working. I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway, I quit with jbpm. Using this method will not fit with my own organization schema, because it is a big scale company higherarchy. I see the method that you are telling allows me to change the place where the actor is stored. But this will cause problems in future while integration and reporting.